# "ad-type-google.com...", "tradeadexchange.com" malware redirection in mobile

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, malware

Whenever I use internet from my home network on my mobile, and open any site, (except Facebook, Yahoo and Youtube), the doesn't load and it redirects to the pages malware pages mentioned in the title. They claim that your mobile has a dangerous virus etc. 
An interesting thing to note is that whenever I switch to request desktop site option, the site opens, but in desktop format. 
It has been more than 8 months like this. I have tried using every antivirus device I have heard of. I have reset my router also. (Because it happens only with **my** router). Also, it doesnt happen on any other device. 
I remember that when it first started, it happened in my laptop also, but after I reset my router, it only happens in my mobile from then. I have tried, if I try it on any other network, malware disappears! I think the malware has been transferred from my router only, to all other devices.? 
Please help! 
**Edit:** As explained in comments, this issue is specifically for a mobile, read the question carefully please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that because he is asking about a mobile device, not a PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it looks like someone has gotten into your router and managed to compromise it at a firmware level.   The answer is to either get another router or to reflash the router firmware with firmware which is known to be good and not vulnerable to the same attack.

As you have not specified your router its difficult to provide more specific details.

Here is an [article from Feb 2015](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2880189/watch-out-for-malware-on-your-router.html) which talks about affected Linksys routers (and a[nother](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/02/bizarre-attack-infects-linksys-routers-with-self-replicating-malware/) one with more details).  This particular attack works in part by changing your home routers DNS settings, so forcing DNS settings in your mobile (if you can do it) may mitigate things.

Here are other versions of the same problem on different [routers](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/how-reset-your-router-rid-it-of-malware-3595477/). - [May 2015](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2921559/malware-vulnerabilities/malware-infected-home-routers-used-to-launch-ddos-attacks.html), - A harmless variant in [October 2015](http://www.securityweek.com/tens-thousands-routers-ip-cams-infected-vigilante-malware).

Here is another article which talks about [DNS Changer Malware](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/dns-changer-malware-sets-sights-on-home-routers/) - which seems to be a likely candidate (although I acknowledge you say you have reset your router - other then that the description matches)

Comment: It is a BSNL Broadband router.

Comment: Look at https://shiningleaf.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/bsnls-dns-is-corrupted-by-malware-for-google-dns-entries/ and https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stop-AdsMatte-spam-popups-and-ads   - Problem could be DNS Changer Malware, but possibly BSNL nameservers.

Comment: A quick test would be to change the nameservers in your router to a different public server, like 4.2.2.1/4.2.2.2 or 8.8.8.8.  You might have to ask BNSL for help on how to do that if you don't know already.  You can also change the DNS directly in your phone, by changing from DHCP to Static IP and listing nameservers there.